# Where does Google Smart Lock have all my passwords from?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I just accidentally noticed that there is this thing called "Smart Lock" in my Google account. (https://passwords.google.com/settings/passwords)

There are 480+ of my passwords stored in there! **Where does it have them from?**

I never used Chrome, so that can't be the reason. Also, there are websites/passwords in there that I haven't used in years! I do have an Android phone, but I'm **very** sure that I've never logged into most of those websites with it. In fact, I've never even visited them with my phone.

*Also, now that I've disabled Smart Lock, I also want to delete all 480+ stored passwords. But it won't let me "delete all" - I have to remove them one by one manually. This is going to take hours! Is there any quicker way?*

Comment: If you truly had never used Chrome and synced your password.  This is the message you would receive "You don't have any passwords saved in Chrome, or you are not syncing them." so given you actually do have passwords saved means your simply mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provied:

> Your passwords from Chrome and Android are saved with Google Smart
>   Lock and accessible to you across devices.

You would have had to have saved them through your phone or via Chrome. AFAIK there's no other way for them to get in there.